# Shutting down 2012 Nexus 7 without touch

Tags: nexus-7, touchscreen, shutdown

My 2012 Nexus 7's touchscreen isn't working. I'll probably take it for repairs next week. Is there a way to shut it down without touch. I can reboot it by keeping power button for a long time, but I am unable to shut it down. I don't think I have USB debugging enabled on the device.

Comment: Since the phone isn't useful without touch, why not just let the battery drain to the point that your Android will auto power off. Or, as jer3my said, a mouse (if you've an OTG cable) would help a lot since USB debugging isn't enabled. // It's odd that your phone just reboots even after pressing power button for 10 seconds or more, since many phones power off in this fashion.

Comment: @Firelord - because it is said that if these batteries remain in fully drained state for too long - they do not charge easily then.

Comment: Yes, I would agree but if the period extends for more than 2-3 weeks, though it's subjective for me considering a battery's technology, so won't disagree here too. Oh, is there a reason why you don't want to or cannot continue running that device and want to power off? I see that its touch is broken but you can just charge it once and let it go to standby until you charge it next time and repeat this cycle until you reach the day for the repairs.

Answer (score 1):

Just tested on my Nexus 7 2012. When I hold the Power and Volume Up. It powers down. Had to hold the power button to get it to turn back on, So I can only assume it powered all the way down.

Comment: Tried this - this also reboots for me.

Comment: Not sure why it works for me, but not for you. =( Do the volume keys work for you, Like if you were trying to adjust the volume? Another idea is, if you have an OTG cable you could plug in a mouse and use it as a pointer to select Power Off from the power menu.

Comment: Yeah, the volume keys work fine for adjusting the volume.